# Conditional expectation of (degenerate) trivariate normal?

Tags: normal-distribution, expected-value, conditional-expectation

Say $A$ and $B$ are both independent, normally distributed. $A\sim\mathcal{N}(\mu_{A},\sigma^{2}_{A})$ and $B\sim\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^{2}_{B})$ define $C=A+B$. Then $(A,B,C)'$ are degenerate, joint trivariate normal because $\rho_{A,C}=\rho_{B,C}=1$ and the correlation matrix of $(A,B,C)'$ is singular.
What would be the conditional expectation $\mathbb{E}[B|C]$?

Naive approach:
Plug in values in the formula for conditional expectation of bivariate normal:
$\mathbb{E}[X|Y]=\mathbb{E}[X]+\rho\frac{\sigma_X}{\sigma_Y}(Y-\mathbb{E}[Y])$

So:
$\mathbb{E}[B|C]=\mu_{B}+(\rho_{B,C})\frac{\sigma^{2}_{B}}{\sigma^{2}_{C}}(C-\mu_{C})=0+(1)\frac{\sigma^{2}_{B}}{\sigma^{2}_{A}+\sigma^{2}_{B}}(C-\mu_C)$

But then I'm stuck for 2 reasons:
(a) Since $C=A+B$ should I write $(A+B-\mu_{A})$?
(b) Does it even make sense to use the formula for the conditional expectation of the bivariate normal by just using $1$ for $\rho=1$?

Comment: those correlations are not 1

Comment: It isn't 1? Then what is it? I thought since C was a linear combination of A and B, then the correlation with A or B would be 1.

Comment: just compute it from variances and covariances: $Cov(A, C) = Var(A)$, $Cov(B, C) = Var(B)$, there is always some variability in C that can't be explained by A or B alone, you need both.

Comment: I see. Thank you. And what about using the formula for the conditional expectation? Is that OK even though C is a function of A and B?

Comment: I don't know it, but... why not?

Comment: Yes, the formula for conditional expectation should work as long as you use it correctly (including not setting correlations to 1 that aren't 1).